# Typescript type guard with optional wrapped type

Tags: typescript

I couldn't find another question that asked this. I am trying to create a type guard that will determine the type of a specific variable. With a singular type it's simple.

```
type A = { id: number, title: string, type: string };
type B = { id: number, title: string, type: string };
type ABUnion = A | B;

const isA = (value: ABUnion): value is A => value.type === 'A';
```

However I have a few scenarios where I have these types wrapped in another type and I want to maintain the wrapped type, but assert that the contained type is what I want it to be.

```
type A = { id: number, title: string, type: string };
type B = { id: number, title: string, type: string };
type ABUnion = A | B | Readonly<A> | Readonly<B>;

const isA = (value: ABUnion): value is A => value.type === 'A';
```

In this scenario I will always get back a typeof A even when I pass a `Readonly<A>` into the guard. I fully expect this to happen.

How can I refactor `isA` to return either `A` or `Readonly<A>` (or another wrapped type)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain I found my own answer pretty quickly after posting this.

```
const isA = <T>(value: T): value is T => value.type === 'A';
```